# How to install Eclipse for C++ for OS X Yosemite?

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, installation

I have a macbook and i'm studying C++ myself. I cant practice it because i don't know how to get eclipse working. Can someone show me exact steps to install eclipse on mac(preferred pictures with notes). Thanks

Comment: Why do you need eclipse? Is it a course requirement? XCode is pretty good (and you're going to need at least the XCode command line tools).

Comment: not for a course. Just friends'  recommendation. how to use Xcode to do this? Can you tell me. Thx.

Comment: To install XCode, open App Store, search for "XCode", click "Install" (or "Download", or whatever it's called). Read the introduction in the extensive built-in help system. (In my experience, Eclipse is nice if you're more interested in configuration and troubleshooting than in programming.)

Comment: Yes. This is so helpful. I tried Xcode which is much easier than Eclipse. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Eclipse CDT](https://eclipse.org/cdt/), unzip it, then "double click" on the "Eclipse" icon in the unzipped folder. This should do it. If you want the debugger to work, that's a different story, you have to use `g++` with `gdb` (Eclipse doesn't work with `lldb`), so you need to install `g++` and `gdb` and [code-sign](http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/) the latter. Easiest way to install them is via [macports](https://www.macports.org/).

PS: to get Eclipse working you need a Java virtual machine, see [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/21/get-java-os-x-yosemite/) how to install it for Yosemite.

BTW: check out the [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) IDE from JetBrains, I find it quite nice. Or, if you want to stick to clang++ use XCode. The only downside in that case is the IDE (I'm not super excited about XCode) and clang++'s lack of OpenMP (which for me was extremely important). You can make OpenMP work with clang++, but it is a pain.

Comment: Yes. I tried but it couldn't work. i can't debug and it doesn't recognise std naming space